# Infer type-safe function signatures in array of piped functions

Tags: typescript, types, pipeline, type-inference

Given the following array of objects with functions to chain sequentially

```
const steps = [
    { description: 'Step 1', execute: () => 1 },
    { description: 'Step 2', execute: (x) => x.toString() },
    { description: 'Step 3', execute: (x) => Boolean(x) },
    { description: 'Step 4', execute: (x) => ({ x }) },
];
```

I wanted to find a way to enfore type-safety between the function calls of two steps. The first iteration ended up as follows:

```
type Step<P, R> = {
  description: string;
  execute(param: P): R;
};
​
type Pipeline<N extends number, R extends unknown[]> = N extends N
  ? number extends N
    ? never
    : FoldPipeline<N, R, []>
  : never;
type FoldPipeline<N extends number, R extends unknown[], A extends unknown[]> =
  A['length'] extends N
    ? A
    : FoldPipeline<
        N,
        R,
        [
          ...A,
          Step<
            A['length'] extends 0
              ? void
              : A extends [...unknown[], Step<unknown, infer P>]
              ? P
              : never,
            R[A['length']]
          >,
        ]
      >;
​
// [Step<void, number>, Step<number, string>, Step<string, boolean>, Step<boolean, object>]
const steps: Pipeline<4, [number, string, boolean, object]> = [
  { description: 'Step 1', execute: () => 1 },
  { description: 'Step 2', execute: x => x.toString() },
  { description: 'Step 3', execute: x => Boolean(x) },
  { description: 'Step 4', execute: x => ({ x }) },
];
```

This works, but the necessity to explicitly list return types along the path is a bit inconvenient albeit safe. Furtheremore there is an edge where passing more types for `R` into `Pipeline` than the number `N` is semantically wrong even though it won't matter for correctness.

What I was curious though, is it possible to define a type `Pipeline` where the type `R` for the second type parameter is deduced from the definition in-place? That is being able to only write `Pipeline<4>` as the type for the `steps` object and having TS infer the types from the return values of the `execute` functions?

Comment: It is possible only during function call. I mean if you pass `steps` to some function, TS will figure it out.

Comment: Please see my article https://catchts.com/FP-style#compose

Comment: @captain-yossarian Do you have any proposal on what such a function, maybe even just an identity for typing purposes may look like? Naively attempting to write `const createPipeline = <N extends number, R extends unknown[]>(steps: Pipeline2<N, R>) => steps;` doesn't work as wished.

Comment: My bad, in this case, you still need to provide explicit type argument for `execute` callback. This is not `F#` where compiler can infer the type from context. In order to do that I'd willing to bet that you should map your `Steps` to types

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know if it works for you:

```js
type Entity = {
    description: string;
    execute: (arg: PropertyKey) => any
}


const builder = <T extends Entity, Steps extends T[]>(steps: [...Steps]) => steps


const result = builder([
    { description: 'Step 1', execute: () => 1 },
    { description: 'Step 2', execute: (x) => x.toString() },
    { description: 'Step 3', execute: (x) => Boolean(x) },
    { description: 'Step 4', execute: (x) => ({ x }) },
]).length // 4

const result_ = builder([
    { description: 'Step 1', execute: () => 1 },
    { description: 'Step 2', execute: (x) => x.toString() },
    { description: 'Step 3', execute: (x) => Boolean(x) },
    { description: 'Step 4', execute: (x) => ({ x }) },
])[0].execute() // number
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogdsAlqKBeKBvAUFXUAmEAzgMYBOiYSA9nAFxRHAVwDmA3DnhAB4QkBXYBAYAKAIZlWDAAplqkMqADSEEAEo0APiji4ILAF8sJkrSZQARgMQAbQmTRQAPABUovYXHxFYCZCAANFAAysJgvp4Q3r6uANoAulqiTBARDHEAdNlhaUQJmqg6qREmWGZwFmTEArbATtZ2DqJxXLgYBMTklDT0UADkuWBQAIz9wbz8QiJQooU6I1CGgW2YnaQUVIi0DIPhUABM4x58gsJiPPNQPJnA1GEsrHNLK3hrhBs92317aVAAzMdJmcZqJLtooAAhajUWwQPRgzTLVYdD7dLY7AZDKAAFiBp2mFyuog6PCWSJWBUycLYwAAFlAAPSM3Gmcz1apEWrAAD6DRs9ggZBaKPW6N6u2xYwmBPOsyui2Rb1RXU2Eqx%20yOMqmcsREJudweiDYzyVeBVnwxP2xgO1IKJEOhsPhcD1ZvaYrV30l%20zxdsJs3BRVmpPJLywBTiAAYEplgdNnsyoHABABbSxCoA)

I assumed, that `execute` can accept only primitive values

> Each parameter x is considered to be of type PropertyKey which isn't deduced

TS is unable to narrow the argument type from the context. There is no such feature.
[image]

For instance, `F#` is able to do it:
[image]

As you might have noticed, F# can figure out that `add` function expects two integers

Comment: Your proposed solution drops all type-safety from the `Entity` objects. Each parameter `x` is considered to be of type `PropertyKey` which isn't deduced.

Comment: Yes you are right. But TS is unable to deduce type of argument from the context. If you want to narrow the `x` you should narrow it from something, but from what? Maybe I did not understand the question